# Angularjs ng-checklist directive binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, checkboxlist

I came across the angular checklist model ,the angularjs directive for list of checkboxes here 
    http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ .
This works fine, but now i want to add into the model only those which are unchecked from the list.means i want the ids of those which are not checked . previously all the values in the list would be checked and if i unchecked a value that would be added in the model.

I am not getting how am i going to  do that .please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use checklist-model as it is. But you'll need to do some coding in the controller, like

```
$scope.$watch("checklistModel", function() {
    $scope.uncheckedOnes = diff($scope.allPossibleValues, $scope.checklistModel);
});
```

where `diff(a,b)` calculates the difference between array `a` and array `b`.